# D3: Circle Points don't update when changing slider

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I've started trying to learn D3 as merely a hobby and I've wanted to create a type of animation that displays the '[method of exhaustion](https://theturnofgears.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/method-of-exhaustion.png)' to approximate the area of a circle. The behavior I wish to obtain is shown in this [animation](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GWC-QyXwH1A/WYLoD8lpbgI/AAAAAAAAJwA/1K3KhZZdITYKtXE_ZoYqDbK3KUE9G64DACJoC/w506-h750/0_ExhaustionMethod_Archimedes.gif).

I have been able to draw the circle, the points around the circle as well as the triangles. Now I am working on a function called 'update' which upon listening to a slider event on the HTML dynamically changes the value for 'n' and use that to recalculate the coordinates and display them on screen.

I have managed to be able to change the fill of the circles but aside from that the update function doesn't update the coordinates of the circles as well as add new circles. I would really appreciate if someone could help me get this working as well as provide some insight as to why my approach is failing.

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 500;
var n = 17;
var r = h / 2 - 20;
var coords = [];
//var id = 0;

function points() {
  coords = []; //Clear Coords Array

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var p_i = {};
    p_i.x = w / 2 + r * math.cos((2 * math.pi / n) * i);
    p_i.y = h / 2 - r * math.sin((2 * math.pi / n) * i);
    p_i.id = i;
    coords.push(p_i);
  }

  //id++;
};

points(); //Generate Points

var svg = d3.select('body') //SVG Canvas
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var circle = svg.append('circle') //Draw Big Circle
  .attr('cx', w / 2)
  .attr('cy', h / 2)
  .attr('r', r)
  .attr('fill', 'teal')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 100);

var center = svg.append('circle') //Construct Center
  .attr('cx', w / 2)
  .attr('cy', h / 2)
  .attr('r', r / 50)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 100);

var approx_pts = svg.selectAll('circle_points') //Construct Approx Points
  .data(coords, function(d) {
    return d.id; //Sets Identifier to uniquely identify data. 
  })
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', w / 100)
  .attr('fill', 'red');

var approx_tri = svg.selectAll('polygon') //Draw Triangles
  .data(coords, function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('polygon')
  .attr('points', function(d, i) {
    if (i != n - 1) {
      return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[i + 1].x + ',' + coords[i + 1].y;
    } else {
      return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[0].x + ',' + coords[0].y;
    }
  })
  .attr('fill', 'Transparent')
  .attr('stroke', 'orange')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 250);

d3.select('#slider') //Listen to Slider Event Change
  .on('input', function() {
    n = +this.value;
    update(n);
  });

function update() {
  console.log('Hey man!');
  points(); // Re-generate points
  console.log('coords[1].x = ' + coords[1].x);
  console.log('coords[1].y = ' + coords[1].y);

  //Make Selection
  approx_pts
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(coords, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  approx_pts
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .attr('r', r / 25);

  approx_pts
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', r / 50)
    .attr('fill', 'green');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.16.2/math.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="3" max="100" step="1" value="3">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a proper "enter", "update" and "exit" selections:

```
var updateSelection = svg.selectAll('.circle_points')
    .data(coords, function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });

var exitSelection = updateSelection.exit().remove();

updateSelection.attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', r / 50)
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .attr('r', r / 25);

var enterSelection = updateSelection.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', r / 50)
    .attr('fill', 'green')
    .attr("class", "circle_points");
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 500;
var n = 17;
var r = h / 2 - 20;
var coords = [];
//var id = 0;

function points() {
  coords = []; //Clear Coords Array

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var p_i = {};
    p_i.x = w / 2 + r * math.cos((2 * math.pi / n) * i);
    p_i.y = h / 2 - r * math.sin((2 * math.pi / n) * i);
    p_i.id = i;
    coords.push(p_i);
  }

  //id++;
};

points(); //Generate Points

var svg = d3.select('body') //SVG Canvas
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var circle = svg.append('circle') //Draw Big Circle
  .attr('cx', w / 2)
  .attr('cy', h / 2)
  .attr('r', r)
  .attr('fill', 'teal')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 100);

var center = svg.append('circle') //Construct Center
  .attr('cx', w / 2)
  .attr('cy', h / 2)
  .attr('r', r / 50)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 100);

var approx_pts = svg.selectAll('circle_points') //Construct Approx Points
  .data(coords, function(d) {
    return d.id; //Sets Identifier to uniquely identify data. 
  })
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', w / 100)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr("class", "circle_points");

var approx_tri = svg.selectAll('polygon') //Draw Triangles
  .data(coords, function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('polygon')
  .attr('points', function(d, i) {
    if (i != n - 1) {
      return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[i + 1].x + ',' + coords[i + 1].y;
    } else {
      return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[0].x + ',' + coords[0].y;
    }
  })
  .attr('fill', 'Transparent')
  .attr('stroke', 'orange')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 250);

d3.select('#slider') //Listen to Slider Event Change
  .on('input', function() {
    n = +this.value;
    update(n);
  });

function update() {
  points(); // Re-generate points

  //Make Selection
  var updateSelection = svg.selectAll('.circle_points')
    .data(coords, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  var exitSelection = updateSelection.exit().remove();

  updateSelection.attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', r / 50)
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .attr('r', r / 25);

  var enterSelection = updateSelection.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', r / 50)
    .attr('fill', 'green')
    .attr("class", "circle_points");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.16.2/math.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="3" max="100" step="1" value="3">
```

Comment: Thank you Gerardo, I have studied the code and I  feel like I understand more in terms of selections, entering and updating to create an animations. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the 'circle_points' and then .exit().remove() and then .enter()

The [Update Pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) is needed here.

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 250;
var n = 4;
var r = h / 2 - 201
var coords = [];
//var id = 0;

function points() {
  coords = []; //Clear Coords Array

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var p_i = {};
    p_i.x = w / 2 + r * math.cos((2 * math.pi / n) * i);
    p_i.y = h / 2 - r * math.sin((2 * math.pi / n) * i);
    p_i.id = i;
    coords.push(p_i);
  }
};

points(); //Generate Points

var svg = d3.select('body') //SVG Canvas
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var circle = svg.append('circle') //Draw Big Circle
  .attr('cx', w / 2)
  .attr('cy', h / 2)
  .attr('r', r)
  .attr('fill', 'teal')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 100);

var center = svg.append('circle') //Construct Center
  .attr('cx', w / 2)
  .attr('cy', h / 2)
  .attr('r', r / 50)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 100);

var approx_pts = svg.selectAll('circle_points') //Construct Approx Points
  .data(coords, function(d) {
    return d.id; //Sets Identifier to uniquely identify data.
  })
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', w / 100)
  .attr('fill', 'red');

var approx_tri = svg.selectAll('polygon') //Draw Triangles
  .data(coords, function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('polygon')
  .attr('points', function(d, i) {
    if (i != n - 1) {
      return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[i + 1].x + ',' + coords[i + 1].y;
    } else {
      return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[0].x + ',' + coords[0].y;
    }
  })
  .attr('fill', 'Transparent')
  .attr('stroke', 'orange')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 250);

d3.select('#slider') //Listen to Slider Event Change
  .on('input', function() {
    n = +this.value;
    update(n);
  });

function update(n) {
  points(); // Re-generate points

  d3.selectAll("circle").remove();
  var approx_pts = svg.selectAll('circle_points') //Construct Approx Points
    .data(coords);

  approx_pts.exit().remove();

  approx_pts.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', 6)
    .attr('fill', 'red');

  d3.selectAll("polygon").remove();
  var approx_tri = svg.selectAll('polygon') //Draw Triangles
    .data(coords)

  approx_tri.exit().remove();

  approx_tri.enter()
    .append('polygon')
    .attr('points', function(d, i) {
      if (i != n - 1) {
        return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[i + 1].x + ',' + coords[i + 1].y;
      } else {
        return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[0].x + ',' + coords[0].y;
      }
    })
    .attr('fill', 'Transparent')
    .attr('stroke', 'orange')
    .attr('stroke-width', w / 250);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.16.2/math.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="3" max="100" step="4" value="17">
</body>
```

Comment: I have and this answer is great! Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: you inspired me, tq

Answer (score 0):

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 500;
var n = 17;
var r = h / 2 - 20;
var coords = [];
//var id = 0;

function points() {
  coords = []; //Clear Coords Array

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var p_i = {};
    p_i.x = w / 2 + r * math.cos((2 * math.pi / n) * i);
    p_i.y = h / 2 - r * math.sin((2 * math.pi / n) * i);
    p_i.id = i;
    coords.push(p_i);
  }

  //id++;
};

points(); //Generate Points

var svg = d3.select('body') //SVG Canvas
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var circle = svg.append('circle') //Draw Big Circle
  .attr('cx', w / 2)
  .attr('cy', h / 2)
  .attr('r', r)
  .attr('fill', 'teal')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 100);

var center = svg.append('circle') //Construct Center
  .attr('cx', w / 2)
  .attr('cy', h / 2)
  .attr('r', r / 50)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 100);

var approx_pts = svg.selectAll('circle_points') //Construct Approx Points
  .data(coords, function(d) {
    return d.id; //Sets Identifier to uniquely identify data. 
  })
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', w / 100)
  .attr('fill', 'red');

var approx_tri = svg.selectAll('polygon') //Draw Triangles
  .data(coords, function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('polygon')
  .attr('points', function(d, i) {
    if (i != n - 1) {
      return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[i + 1].x + ',' + coords[i + 1].y;
    } else {
      return w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ' ' + coords[0].x + ',' + coords[0].y;
    }
  })
  .attr('fill', 'Transparent')
  .attr('stroke', 'orange')
  .attr('stroke-width', w / 250);

d3.select('#slider') //Listen to Slider Event Change
  .on('input', function() {
    n = +this.value;
    update(n);
  });

function update(n) {
  //console.log('Hey man!');
  points(); // Re-generate points
  //console.log('coords[1].x = ' + coords[1].x);
  //console.log('coords[1].y = ' + coords[1].y);

  //Make Selection
  approx_pts
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(coords, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  approx_pts
.attr('fill', 'blue')
.attr('r', r / 25);


  approx_pts
   
.attr('cx', function(d) {

  return (d.x)+n;
})
.attr('cy', function(d) {
  return d.y+n;
})
.attr('r', r / 50)
.attr('fill', 'green');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.16.2/math.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="3" max="100" step="1" value="3">
```

> remember to update the value when you drag it

Comment: The code only changes the radius of the circles around the big circle but does not change their coordinates according to the value for n. Which subdivides the circle into equal pieces. The behavior I wish to get is shown here: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GWC-QyXwH1A/WYLoD8lpbgI/AAAAAAAAJwA/1K3KhZZdITYKtXE_ZoYqDbK3KUE9G64DACJoC/w506-h750/0_ExhaustionMethod_Archimedes.gif

Comment: i am noob i just want to help, but you not appreciated that, you say change their coordinates according to the value for n,right?, im done edit that sorry for my wrong answer

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but you should have your value on the slider the same as the initial n     <input id="slider" type="range" min="3" max="100" step="1" value="17">